# Solving inequalities and how to separate the results

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Problem:

> If $2a-3d<2x-3y<2b-3c$, which one of the options is true?
>
> 1. $a>x>b$ and $c<y<d$
> 2. $a<x>b$ and $c>y<d$
> 3. $a\leq x \leq b$ and $c\geq x \geq d$
> 4. $a<x<b$ and $c<y<d$
> 5. $a \geq x \geq b$ and $c\leq y \leq d$

Is there a direct way to solve this problem algebraically without guessing which one is correct? I've tried something like this:

$a-\frac 32d+\frac 32y<x<b-\frac 32c+\frac 32y$,

$-\frac 23a+d-\frac 23y + 2x>y>-\frac 23b+c - \frac 23x$

But I'm stuck and I don't know whether they would help or not. Help? No need to directly give me the answer, but I hope you will add the explanation instead and a guide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "...which one of the options is true?" Could this be a typo?  Could the intended question actually be: "...which one of the options **might** be true"?

Comment: @user2661923 I actually made up the translation. Please apologize my English. It's literally translated as (if bla bla bla, then bla bla) I added which one of the options is true bcz I thought it would help you all to understand what kind of answer I want. Since 5xum have shown that it's unlikely the question's got an answer, perhaps there's a way to find the solution though?

Comment: You need to clarify the problem composer's intent.  Is the problem composer asking which of the options (if any) have to be true, or is the problem composer asking which of the options (if any) might be true?

Comment: @user2661923 it says here there must be one answer, so it's possibly a typo if there's no possible answer. It's taken from  a multiple-choice test. I were to give this problem to my student. Guess I just could skip it then.

Comment: Objection, non-responsive.  The stipulation that there must be one answer does not address the underlying question of whether, what is being asked is whether there is an option that has to be correct, or whether there is an option that might be correct.  That is, it might be that all of the options are impossible except one of the options, and it might be that the problem composer is asking you which option might be true, rather than which option has to be true.

Comment: @user2661923 it's a multiple choice type sir. In my country, there's always only one answer of a multiple choice question, unless it's a typo. Also, the instruction says "pick only one answer", so... Anyway, I've added "which one of the options is true" to indicate that the problem has one solution. Probably I should add that the question might be poorly written, at least in my opinion. (It's not made by me though)

Comment: Again, non-responsive.  Are you sure that the question was asking which option has to be true, rather than asking which option is not impossible?

Comment: @user2661923 read the middle sentence sir. I'm sorry, but I'm afraid I can't continue this. It's supposed to be a discussion. I've clearly said that the question must be one answer. 1) which one of the options is true 2) it says here there must be one answer 3) ... there's only one answer of a multiple choice question. If it's not clear, I'll repeat again, the instruction on the paper says that I have to choose only 1 answer, and that 1 answer must be correct. If I choose the other answer and it turns out to be incorrect, then my answer is incorrect. I couldn't think of anyhow more than that.

Answer (score 1):

Neither option can be concluded just from what we have. That is, for any of the five statements, it is possible that they are false even if the statement $2a-3d<2x-3y<2b-3c$ is true.

---

First look at the possibility that $x=y=0, a=-1,b=1,c=d=0$

- Because in this case, $x>a$, we see that options $1$ and $5$ might not be true.
- Because $x<b$, we see that option $2$ might not be true.
- Because $y=c$, we see that option $4$ might not be true.

Now, look at the possibility that $a=d=0, x=1, y=0, b=2,c=0$.

In this case, because $x>c$, we see that option $3$ might not be true.

Comment: Great thanks, regardless the options, could I really get to know the interval solutions of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: @user516076 If you mean an interval for $x$, then no. For any collection of $a,b,c,d,x$, there exists some $y$ such that the original inequality is satisfied. This means that $x$ can be anything.

Comment: Consider the back and forth comments following the original question.  It seems plausible to me that the problem composer is actually asking which of the $5$ options is not impossible, rather than asking which of the $5$ options has to be true.  That is, the OP indicated that he added his own interpretive translation to the question, that was originally posed in a different language.  Personally, I think that it would be worthwhile for you to explore this alternate interpretation of the problem.